# How is "--" changed to "—" within Mail, TextEdit…?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I just incidentally discovered that within Mail, TextEdit when typing two dashes in a row, the string "--" is instantaneously changed to "—" (i.e. a long dash).

This magic is mostly loathsome when you need to type exactly "--",
you didn't notice this magic and wasted hours searching why a correct syntax isn't where you typed it. With small fonts this magic change is hard to notice.

This function doesn't exist on Lion and Mountain Lion.

This magic but as unwanted as ununderstood feature raises 3 questions.

---

Where is this function configured?

How may I get rid of it?

Is this magic useful?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Edit > Substitutions > Untick "Smart dashes". Then relaunch "TextEdit". Same with "Mail".

[image]

To your third q: It is simply more beautiful. Personally I don't like when people type long dashes by using two short ones.

A tip: you can type long one even with "smart dashes" disabled with <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> (short dash).

Comment: Thank you for the useful tip.
I highly prefer the ergonomy of the `[⌥ option]+[-]` (when I need it) to an hidden menu entry (which meaning isn't as straight).

Comment: "I don't like when people type long dashes by using two short ones."  Agreed, but in addition to the em-dash (long dash), there's also the en-dash for numeric ranges.  LaTeX uses `-` for a hyphen, `--` for en-dashes, and `---` for em-dashes.  It'd be nice if the autoreplacement mimicked that (but it *is* more common to see `--` used in plain text to simulate an em-dash).

Answer (score 7):

System Prefs > Keyboard > Text
Uncheck "Use smart quotes & dashes"

[image]

Comment: Nice idea :). Working for `Textedit` on `Mavericks` but failing for `Mail` on `Mavericks`. I'll check on `Yosemite` next time Apple will give us an interesting bug fix set to check.

Comment: @dan How does it look better when formatted as code?

Comment: Are you speaking of the HTML style used for reserved words as in `Mail`?

Comment: @daniel Code markup should be used for code, see http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/markup-of-reserved-words/2199#2199

Comment: Which markup **should** be used for reserved words so as to disambiguate easily and for everyone two words as in: `Mail` and Mail?

Comment: I'd disambiguate Mail as Mail.app though it's usually clear enough in context

Comment: This isn't readable for "everyone". Hint: evaluate the percentage of users who know the extensions of file names on MacOS X.

Comment: even 6-year-olds know what an app is these days.

Answer (score 7):

If you'd still prefer substitutions to be enabled, but just want to undo a substitution one time, immediately after the substitution occurs simply press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> (or Edit → Undo). I suppose this isn't too well-known; I recall myself finding out only by coincidence. The downside to this is the substitution will be selected so you need to press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> to jump back to the end.

[image: Demo]